# WebSphere 400 server error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere

Having a strange issue on IBM Websphare server from two weeks. I am initiating a SOAP call to an external application connecting to a windows webservice.

The purpose is to upload documents directly to the Document Management System.

The request from IBM server doesn't reaches the windows IIS server for documents more than 600KB where as below 600KB upload is working perfectly fine.

The same call was working for more than a year and suddenly something has changed by which the issue is untraceable.

Below are the steps which are taken into consideration

1. Document upload limits are set to above 4 MB on both the IBM and IIS Servers.
2. THe call from IBM server to DMS server is passed through Network load balancers.
3. IBM servers are two node where as DMS server is 1 node.
4. call is not reaching the DMS server for more than 800kb document.
5. DOcuments are being sent as a base64string
6. IBM Websphare logs are showing 400 http server error for failed request and no footprints found on the DMS Server.

Now I am suspecting the issue is on the Network side , but how to further more troubleshoot the 400 error in details ? how to get to the root of this call ?

can wireshark can provide the trace from the network side?

Comment: I have once encountered a problem where a firewall was dropping requests above a certain size, because the size of the request exceeded an internally-configured buffer size parameter. See if you can add a firewall exception between the servers.

Comment: @Xsurgent unfortunately no packet loss at the firewall

Comment: Perhaps you can find further help over at Server Fault.